# ElasticsearchException: Failure running machine learning native code

Tags: elasticsearch

i am learning Elasticsearch and tried to install it on my windows 8 (64 bit) machine.
firstly i tried to install in using zip file [downalod elasricsearch](https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.3.2-windows-x86_64.zip)

but that didn't worked for me, the command prompt gets closed after this[image: after executing upto this level(see the image)]

after that i tried installing elasticsearch using windows installer (MSI).
but i ended up having this[image]

i found one cause for this error on internet that environment is not 64bit but in my case it is..please give me some sollution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can append a config line

```
xpack.ml.enabled: false
```

in config file ${elastic_search_home}/config/elasticsearch.yml to bypass this problem.

Answer (score 2):

In case you run in **Docker container**  you can disable machine learning functionality setting environment variable `-e "xpack.ml.enabled=false"`.

Answer (score 1):

**For Mac Users**

On OSX installed with Homebrew
Add: xpack.ml.enabled: false
To: /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
And restart: brew services restart elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full